# Including "Yield" in Application Helper in Ruby on Rails

Tags: helper, railstutorial.org, yield

In Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial he suggests you create a "Full Title" helper as below:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

The following is then added to the application.html.erb file:

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:page_title)) %></title>
```

The above is not human readable and is difficult to parse. This would be much easier to understand and would encapsulate the full logic for generating titles within the helper. Why not move the yield into the helper and use something like this:

```
<title><%= full_title(:page_title) %></title>
```

**Is there a Ruby/Rails convention against placing "yield" within a helper?**

Answer (score 1):

there is no convention yet for this, but you can still improve this a little

```
#application.html.erb
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App<%= yield :title %></title>
</head>

#application_helper.rb
def title(title)
    content_for(:title) { " | #{title}" }
end

#Any page
<% title "My title" %>
#or a translation
<% title t("titles.my_title") %>
```